# Responsive tables: show thead elements' content in corresponding tds

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, col

I have tables similar to this simplified version:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th></th>
            <th>1st sg.</th><th>2nd</th><th>3rd...</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Present</th>
            <td>sum</td><td>es</td><td>est...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><th>Perfect</th>
            <td>fui</td><td>fuisti</td><td>fuit...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And they do become quite wide. So I `display: block` all table elements, aside from thead which is `display:none`, [Semantic UI style](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html).

Which works pretty well as is. But I still would the content from the `ths` of `thead` to be still noticeable.

I think of using jQuery and dynamically adding an attribute called `col` or `data-col`, as can be seen started in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk8g2sd9/).

The dynamically created code would than be similar to the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Present</th>
        <td data-col="1st sg.">sum</td>
        <td data-col="2nd">es</td>
        <td data-col="3rd">est</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So my technical question is the following:

**How can I dynamically get the content from a thead's th elements, and distribute said content to all tds of the same column as an attribute?**

Other solutions are appreciated as well!

Comment: did not get your problem, what do you mean by "distribute it back to all corresponding tds as an attribute"?

Comment: Sorry my English is not perfect ^^' I mean something similar to Thead:Th(1):content => Tbody:Tr(a):Td(1):attribute, Tbody:Tr(b):Td(1):attribute and so forth

Comment: thats ok, but please try to explain what exactly you want to do? explain it by given code example. here `<th>1st sg.</th>` where you want to put in table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a javascript function. See if this helps

```
    function td_col()
    {
        var table = $('table');
        table.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
            $(this).find('td').each(function(i){ 
               $(this).attr('data-col', table.find('thead tr th:eq('+(i + 1)+')').html());
            })
        })
    }
```

CSS Update :

```
        @media(max-width:470px) {
        td:before {
            float:right;
            content:attr(data-col); //Removed the brackets.
        }
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jk8g2sd9/1/)

Comment: I love you! That was incredibly fast, what's your secret?

Comment: Nothing much, just drink lots of water :D

Comment: That's what I do all day drink water -_- oh well. But seriously thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh Small problem though, when there is more than one table on the page, it gives the same attributes from the first thead to the following tables...

Comment: pass an argument in the function i.e the id or the instance of the table.

Comment: Cool! Got it to work by wrapping the function with `$('table').each()`. I have to admit not being a strong javascripter. Your answer makes me understanding it more :)